# Unable to load SWIRL package in R Studio

Tags: r, package, swirl

I am getting the following error on loading the swirl package

```
library("swirl", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
Error : .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'swirl', details:
call: str_c(..., sep = " ")
error: lazy-load database '/home/ganesh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library  /3.2/stringi/R/stringi.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In str_c(..., sep = " ") : restarting interrupted promise evaluation
2: In str_c(..., sep = " ") : internal error -3 in R_decompress1
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘swirl’
```

As you can see R version is 3.2 and it is running on Ubuntu 15.04 64 bit.

Request your help.

Thanks

Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 15.04 here too and all is well:

```
edd@max:~$ install.r swirl          ## install.r is part of littler
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/swirl_2.2.21.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 51037 bytes (49 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 49 KB

* installing *source* package ‘swirl’ ...
** package ‘swirl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (swirl)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
edd@max:~$ r -e 'library(swirl); cat("All OK\n")'

| Hi! I see that you have some variables saved in your workspace. To keep
| things running smoothly, I recommend you clean up before starting swirl.

| Type ls() to see a list of the variables in your workspace. Then, type
| rm(list=ls()) to clear your workspace.

| Type swirl() when you are ready to begin.

All OK
edd@max:~$
```

As you can see, the package installs cleanly here, does not require any depends (maybe because I already have a fair number of packages installed) and loads just fine.

I install and test frequently from the command-line and use the `install.r` wrapper in [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) -- do `sudo apt-get install littler` if you want to install that first.

Comment: Thanks but the issue was with STRINGI package. I reinstalled the stringi package and swirl worked fine.